# My Symfony Entity does not publish an Update on an Get-Operation with an modified uriTemplate-Url

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, operation, mercure

In an Symfony-Entity (using Apiplattform and ApiResource-Definitions) I added a second Get-Operation like

```
#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new Get(),
    new Get(uriTemplate: '/[pathtoEntity]/{id}',
        provider: [myOwnRepresentationProvider]::class),
mercure:true)]
```

However an update on the resource is only published to the original url of the entity, not on my second get-operation.

Where do I need to hook in to publish on the second get-operation or even to distiguish between the two. Or is that not possible?

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I found the answer: I needed to publish my data manually on the new uriTemplate-Path. Im trying to do that in the persister. seems to work.